# Adding Header and Footer to JSON output from Python

Tags: python, json, header

I need to export a file in JSON format and would love to add the needed headers and footers within the Python code instead of having to manually add after producing the file. Below is the package and code I use to export the JSON file.

```
df.to_json(r'S:\\JSON Folder\Example.json')

df.to_json(r'S:\S:\\JSON Folder\Example.json')
out = df.to_json(orient='records')[1:-1].replace('},{', '}, {')

with open(r'S:\JSON Folder\Output.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(out)
```

I would like to add this header:

```
{"Example_File":{
"description":"Example_Ver_1",
"fileType":"EXAMP",
"fullFileReplace":"Y",
"Data": [
```

And this footer:

```
]
}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!
Phil

Answer (score 0):

Why not just work it as a json?

```
out=df.to_json(r'S:\\JSON Folder\Example.json')
b={"Example_File":{
"description":"Example_Ver_1",
"fileType":"EXAMP",
"fullFileReplace":"Y"}}
b["Example_File"]["Data"]=[out]
with open(r'S:\JSON Folder\Output.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(b))
```

Comment: Not sure if I'm following, but to clarify, should I do something like this? df.to_json(r'S:\NonhealthcareDebitCard\PII\Card Analytics\Kim Folder\VCS_kim.json')
b={"Example_File":{
"description":"Example_Ver_1",
"fileType":"EXAMP",
"fullFileReplace":"Y"}}
b["Example_File"]["Data"]=[out]
out = df.to_json(orient='records')[1:-1].replace('},{', '}, {')

Comment: I received an error that name 'out' is not defined.

Comment: did you declare out like in the first line in the answer?

Comment: I reworked the code and now the header/footer work great. The issue I'm getting now is Null data. When I retrieved my output, this was the result. {"Cardholder_Consumer_File": {"description": "Cardholder_File_Ver_1", "fileType": "CRDH", "crdhType": "ACCT_NUM", "fullFileReplaceIndCrdh": "Y", "cardholderConsumerData": null}}

Comment: OK, I think I almost go it but now I'm seeing \ in my data and it looks like this: \",\"CNTRY_CD\":\"840\",\"PRMRY_EMAIL_ADDR\":\"\",\"ISSR_COMM_DRCT_MAIL_OPTIN_FLG\":\"Y\",\"  My out looks like this, but the rest matches your code. out = df.to_json(orient='records')[1:-1].replace('},{', '}, {')  I had to add commas to make it match the format requested.

Comment: Thats probably because you added json.dumps twice.

Comment: Not seeing where I added json.dumps twice. Here is my new code. I still have the \ marks. out = df.to_json(orient='records')[1:-1].replace('},{', '}, {') b={"Cardholder_Consumer_File":{
"description":"Cardholder_Consumer_File_Ver_1",
"fileType":"CRDH",
"crdhType":"ACCT_NUM",
"fullFileReplaceIndCrdh":"Y"}}
b["Cardholder_Consumer_File"]["cardholderConsumerData"]=[out]
with open(r'S:\Example\Example.YYYYMMDD.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(b))